# How can I activate or deactivate my own microphone in a conference in circuit?

Tags: circuit, circuit-sdk

How can I activate or deactivate my own microphone in a conference? we used this:

client.muteDevice(call.callId, null, {mic: true, speaker: true})

but give error

Answer (score 1):

The API [mute](https://circuitsandbox.net/sdk/classes/Client.html#method_mute) should work to mute your default mic. muteDevice is to mute another of your devices, e.g. if you are logged on with your Circuit webclient on another PC and that client is on the active call.

Example:

```
client.mute(call.callId).then(() => {
  console.log('Unmuted');
}).catch(err => {
  console.error('Failed to mute. ', err);
});
```

Complete example with a call is shown at https://output.jsbin.com/posoko

Comment: Update original answer with an example and a jsbin